# Google App Engine GQL Query ORDER BY date_posted

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web.py

I have the following model:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    author = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    content = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    date_posted = db.DateTimeProperty()
```

And the following GQL query:

```
db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Post ORDER BY date_posted LIMIT 10")
```

Yet the posts are still displayed in a seemingly random order. What am I doing wrong?

Using framework: Web.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't you forget to correctly set date_posted? Or maybe you wanted model to auto assign current time? If so, you have forgot to set auto_now_add=True:

```
date_posted = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```